# How to add a prefix to unique ID using Attribute Assistant?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tools, attribute-assistant

I want to add a prefix to my unique id field; for example, “MH123”.  I am currently using Attribute Assistant Tool. How can I edit my Dynamic Value Table to add a prefix to my unique ID?

Comment: There is fairly comprehensive documentation on this AddIn [here](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [Generate ID](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-sequences-and-id/#generate-id). The examples have examples using hydrants, but it's easy to extend for manholes:

> > > Appends the HYDSEQ value to the text "Hydrant-". In this example, if the HYDSEQ is 7, 39, or 1234 then the HYDID will be Hydrant-7, Hydrant-39, or Hydrant-1234, respectively:

```
Table Name: hydrants
Field Name: HYDID
Value Info: HYDSEQ||Hydrant-[SEQ]
```

The dynamic value table stores the counter that is incremented each time the rule is triggered.